# Grunt And bower automatic dependency

Tags: bower, grunt-contrib-copy, gruntfile

I am using bower And grunt for my web app,  by now I had some issues trying to import resources to the dist/ directory. I am using material design icons but I need just few of them. By now the only chance that I've got is to manually tell grunt what to copy in the copy task. Is there a way to have this automatically done just for the resources used?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that is not possible unless you manually find a way to scan your css and HTML files. Sounds like you need to write your own gulp module or search an existing one on the internet.